# Java server, post parameter is null

Tags: java, rest, post

The server side is Java and it looks like this:

```
@post
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) //APPLICATION_JSON
@consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) //APPLICATION_JSON
@path("/signup")
public String update_signup(@PathParam("data") String data)
```

I also tried like this

```
public String update_signup(@PathParam("data") JSONObject data)
```

but no matter how I configure the post command (using Rested (firefox addon) or postman (Windows)), the parameter data is null on the server side. Several options fail with 415 or 405 but those that work, I see null in the data parameter value.

What am I missing?
I read about

Thanks

Comment: First of all `@pathparam` all is lowercase it should be @PathParam.

Comment: Not sure why the copy paste made it lowercase but it is @PathParam in the code

Comment: On `@Path("/signup/{data}")` You have to pass data if the parameter type is String then it will get matched.

Comment: You got a point there, silly me. Now I keep getting 404. Eventually I will need a JSONObject so the type is string but the content is structured as JSON so whatever works (json/text), I'll be happy with it

Comment: Thinking about it, in POST I think there is no need for the additional {data}

Comment: If data is not part of url then there should be some other way you are passing the data. You can pass {data} as part of the URL in POST as well.

Comment: Once I removed the {data} 404 is gone and the null is back. I pass it in the request body as data -> {"name":"blah"} but the server gets null

Comment: Apparently "@FormParam" is the answer and now it's working using my rest client addon (firefox), I wonder if it will keep working when the client is also Java (Android)

Comment: Cool. I was about to say `@FormParam` after seeing your request format.